# Should I choose one of RDD or DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark(or Spark), we can use both of RDD and DataFrame structure. Should I choose one of these?

I feel some jobs are easy by RDD, another jobs are easy by DataFrame. What is typical programming convention? I think I am using too many `.rdd` and `.toDF()`.

Comment: It depends on requirement or how you're trying to do the task. Both RDD and DF are inside memory. Dataframes makes SQL queries easier to perform and RDD can be used for other tasks. It depends on whether you're dealing with structured and unstructured data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General recommendation to stick to Dataframes as Spark may use more compact representation for data, and also perform a lot of code optimizations when processing your data, while for RDD these optimizations aren't performed. In some cases you may need to go back to RDDs, but this shouldn't happen very often.

P.S. I recommend to skim through Learning Spark, 2ed that is [freely available from Databricks](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly) - it covers these topics as well.